# FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected() crashes only on Android Oreo

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

When requesting permission for fingerprint sensor manually for oreo dialog box does not show up.

I have listed the USE_FINGERPRINT permission in Manifest but still, I get an exception as

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.SecurityException: Must have android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT permission.: Neither user 10190 nor current process has android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT.
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2004)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1950)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService$Stub$Proxy.isHardwareDetected(IFingerprintService.java:465)
        at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.isHardwareDetected(FingerprintManager.java:835)
        at ""ui.biometricAuth.BiometricAuth.getFingerPrintAuthError(BiometricAuth.java:174)
        at ""ui.biometricAuth.BiometricAuth.isTouchIDEnabled(BiometricAuth.java:225)
        at ""ui.usermanagement.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:403)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027)
 W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1231)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2864)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2989)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1688)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6753)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:482)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: check if you declared permission correctly

Comment: @Pankaj Kumar  Yes I have done it the right way, It works on other versions only crashes for Oreo

Comment: What devices are you testing on that are failing? I have had no problems using `USE_FINGERPRINT` on Android 8.x devices. See [this project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.12/DeviceAuth/FingerCheck) for example. I happen to be using the `RxFingerprint` library for a reactive layer atop the fingerprint APIs, but that should not matter here.

Comment: @CommonsWare While searching for this issue I found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37120754 and it is still in assigned state. So it seems many are facing similar issue

Comment: I am using oneplus 5 with Oreo OS on it

Comment: I've seen a similar problem on the Galaxy S7, where `hasEnrolledFingerprints()` sometimes would cause a `SecurityException` the first time I called it after rebooting the phone. That issue seemed to go away if I called `isHardwareDetected` before `hasEnrolledFingerprints`, but I wrapped the whole thing in `try { } catch (SecurityException) {}` just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the permission as follows before

```
<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT"
    android:requiredFeature="false" />
```

now after removing android:requiredFeature="false" and adding only

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT" />
```

worked fine for all the OS versions.

Comment: I already had this permission without `requiredFeature` and it is still crashing for me. However, I just get a nullpointer when retrieving the `FINGERPRINT_SERVICE`, not a permission error like the topic starter.

Comment: were you able to fix this ? @Peterdk

Answer (score 0):

A clean build (or just rebuild) works too.

Answer (score -3):

add android.permission.USE_BIOMETRIC

Comment: This app crashes on Android 8.x; `USE_BIOMETRIC` was not added until the P Developer Preview.